# PostgresSQL could not load library plpython3.dll

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-12, plpython

I managed to install the plpython3u extention. But when I try to use a function that uses the extension I get:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/lib/plpython3.dll": unknown error 126 SQL state: 58P01
```

I'm using windows 10 and postgresql 12.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply solve this problem by installing the right (preferable version is in between 3.5.x to 3.8.x ) version of python and add paths to environment variables.

Steps:

Download and install the latest python version from this [Download latest python version 3.8.x](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Add environment variable:

1. C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts
2. C:\Program Files\Python38

Comment: I had alreary done this and still don't work. Do you have any guess of what else can be wrong?

Comment: For this now, i think, you have to copy the mentioned dll file from system32 folder to its original folder and do some extra bits of work. I request you to follow the steps to solve your problem from this link (https://postgresrocks.enterprisedb.com/t5/PostgreSQL/unable-to-install-pl-python-extension/td-p/4059/)